# How to get buyer email after payment paypal button

Tags: paypal

I want to get buyer email after the buyer pays on paypal, i have generated the button code, i searched in documents but couldnt find a solution to this, should i be passing any hidden variable? I did try but doesnt work. Plz help

The button code I want to use

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="YC5HJC37YASFG">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/FR/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal, le réflexe sécurité pour payer en ligne">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/fr_FR/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

The code I tried with different button code and it works.

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="abc@mysite.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="DSF_SYSCOHADA_GABON_v7.xlsx">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="DSF TEST">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="TEST01">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://abcdotcom/paypaltest/return.php">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://abcdotcom/paypaltest/notify.php">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
```

Comment: What did you try? How are you getting anything? Any way you are receiving information from PayPal will contain the buyer's email.

Comment: Hi, I have added the tried code to the question, kindly check. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That other button's code has a `notify_url` for IPN, and is unhosted. If you want to include the notify_url as part of the hosted button's parameters, edit the hosted button via https://www.paypal.com/buttons and add the parameter in Step 3's advanced variables section.

Comment: Thank you, I was using personal account, so when I tried business account, I got the options to pass custom parameters, Thank you.